# Jenkins Log Parser rules

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, logparser

I am using the [Jenkins Log Parser Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) as a post-build step to check for errors after builds

I have all my rules in a file and the notation supports the Java regex embedded flag expression:

```
# list keywords or regex for ERRORS:
error /(?i)error/
error / (?i)error/
error /(?i)error /
error / (?i)error /

error /(?i)error:/
error / (?i)error:/
error /(?i)error: /
error / (?i)error: /

error /Unknown database/
error /Connect failed/
error /(?i)undefined/
error /Call Stack:/



# list keywords or regex for WARNINGS:
warning /(?i)^warning/
warning /(?i)warning/
warning /(?i)warning:/
```

My problem is that I am not so good with regex expressions, and every time it encounters a word that contains "error" it triggers an alarm. For example: T**error** or Biot**error** (and I know it may come from my bad expressions, but if I mark "Bioterror" or "Terror" as warning, it still overwrites them as errors and triggers the alarm).

My questions are:

1. what is the proper way to exclude certain words defined by me?
2. is this achievable? (I thought this is the way the plugin works, since if I mark the necessary words as warnings it still highlights them as errors)

Comment: If you have problem with regexp try to  build your expression in one of online regex pages.
https://regex101.com/  or http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a word-boundary anchor, which is `\b` in most regex flavors. It's zero-width, so it doesn't match any character, just the switch from non-word to word characters.

So your match would become:

`error /(?i)\berror\b/`

That one regex handles all the cases it looked like you were trying to handle separately: space before or after, colon after, etc.

Comment: thanks @Brian , I've tested it and it works. Also big thanks for letting me know of the redundant expressions.